# MrSid layer not showing up using GeoServer 2.5.2

Tags: geoserver, mrsid

I am using GeoServer 2.5.2 on windows.  It is running as a service.  I followed all the steps to add the MrSID support to geoserver. Now I have the option to select MrSID Raster Data Source. I select MrSid and setup the store (Add Raster Data Source):

```
Workspace: cite
Data Source Name: test1
Description: test1
Enabled: true
URL: file:data/MrSID/test1.sid
```

I then click on the SAVE button. Now I get to the "New Layer" screen:

```
Published   Layer name               Action 
            geotools_coverage        Publish
```

At this point I click on "Publish". Now I get to the "Edit Layer" screen:

```
name: test1
enabled: true
advertised: true
title: test1
etc
```

I click on "Save" at the bottom of the page.  I then click on "Layer Preview" on the left side menu of GeoServer. The new layer is not there.  What step(s) did I miss?

Comment: what is in the log file?

Answer (score 1):

This GeoServer version 2.5.2 has got to be one of the most bug-prone software I have ever used!  I finally figured out why it was not creating the layer.  First of all, it creates a folder with an incomplete file (workspace.xml):

...\Program Files\GeoServer 2.5.2\data_dir\workspaces\cite\test1

Then the trick to it is, once you click on the "publish" link and get to the "Edit layers" screen, you have to click on **EVERY** tab and then scroll to the bottom and click on "save" on **EVERY** tab!  Once you do that, it will create a subfolder:

...\Program Files\GeoServer 2.5.2\data_dir\workspaces\cite\test1\test1

With two more files (coverage.xml and layer.xml).  At this point you can now click on the link on the left hand side titled "Layer Preview" and the new layer will be there.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
this behaviour is actually strange, aside from possibly being a bug I would suggest you to do the following checks:

-1- make sure that the service has enough rights to write in the location where the data dir is placed. If the service user cannot correctly interact with the filesystem then you can have problems at runtime when adding data i.e. creating config files beind the curtains on that file system
-2- personal advice, don't install geoserver in paths with spaces. It should not be a problem but better being on the safe side.

A few general advices:
-1- I believe you are using the exe provided with GeoServer and then you installed as a service. Well, the recommended way of production use is to use the WAR release with the APplication Server of your choice (we usually recommend Tomcat).
-2- Report this kind of problems to the mailing list otherwise you are forcing the developers to do extra work to keep an eye here as well. If this is a bug how do we'll even know about it if it is not reported?

Anyway, I just download the zip for 2.5.2, installed the gdal extension and then I tested it with some data of my own and I did not experience this problem. 
I will do the same for the service, just for curiosity.

Simone.

Comment: I already checked all your suggestions.  Glad it worked for you!